# How to test aws lambda functions locally

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a mobile application backend developed with node.js express. I tried it to deploy it as lambda service. For that I created a Serverless Framework project (https://github.com/serverless). Previously I tested mobile app locally by starting express backend application. Now I can't find a method to test my mobile app locally without local backend. `jaws run` command only run once I called it.

Is there any method to start the lambda function as a web service? Or is there any alternative to Serverless Framework?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's way to do this right now, but version 1.4.0 is about to be released and, among other things, it should include a new command "jaws serve" which should address your problem.

Here's the PR: https://github.com/jaws-framework/JAWS/pull/269

UPDATE: you can now use the new [serverless-serve](https://github.com/Nopik/serverless-serve) plugin for this.

UPDATE 2: serverless-serve hasn't been updated in a while, it looks like [serverless-offline](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline) is a much better option now to emulate Lambda functions.

Comment: Thanks, serverless can be used not only for offline test but it also helps to deploy and other lots of stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You can now use [lambda-local](https://github.com/ashiina/lambda-local).

Install it like this:

```
sudo -H npm install -g lambda-local
```

Add your parameters as a JSON object to a file, in this example `event.json`, and call the `index.js` file like this:

```
lambda-local -l index.js -h handler -e event.json
```

Comment: Doesn't support everything but at least that's very light

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this question is still relevant or not, but I'm using [DEEP Framework](https://github.com/MitocGroup/deep-framework) to test the code locally and/or deploy it on AWS Lambda. Check this out:

```
npm install deepify -g

deepify run-lambda --help

  run-lambda@1.6.8 - Run Lambda function locally 

  Usage example: deepify run-lambda path/to/the/lambda -e='{"Name":"John Doe"}' 

  Arguments:  
    path: The path to the Lambda (directory of handler itself) 

  Options:  
    --event|-e: JSON string used as the Lambda payload 
    --skip-frontend-build|-f: Skip picking up _build path from the microservices Frontend 
    --db-server|-l: Local DynamoDB server implementation (ex. LocalDynamo, Dynalite) 
    --version|-v: Prints command version 
    --help|-h: Prints command help
```

*Disclosure: I am one of the contributors to this framework*

Comment: can't get this to work :/ hangs after "starting lambda".

Answer (score 3):

[The serverless framework now provide a way to invoke functions locally](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke-local/)

With that, you can create queries in json files like

```
{
  "body": "{\"hello\":\"world\"}",
  "pathParameters": {
    "id": "foo"
  },
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "bar": "42"
  }
  "requestContext": {
    "identity": {
      "cognitoIdentityId": "cognito-id"
    }
  }
}
```

If your function is described in `serverless.yml` file, you can then invoke it locally with

```
serverless invoke local --function yourFunction --path path/to/your/mock.json
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Bespoken sevrerless plugin](https://github.com/bespoken/serverless-plugin-bespoken) makes your local Lambdas externally accessible. It is very useful both for local testing with Postman as well as for Webhook-based services (like Alexa, Slack, Twilio, etc.).

The architecture is shown here:
[image]

To use it, you just install the plugin, then run:

```
sls proxy
```

You can then start sending requests to your service locally:

[image]

We think it is a very useful tool for testing with serverless.

Answer (score 2):

This may be too late.. But now you can try Serverless-Offline (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline) works like a charm

Also this is the github page for it (https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Python

An example `lambda_function.py`:

```
def lambda_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    return 'hello'
```

Example invocation of a local lambda function:

```
pip install python-lambda-local
echo '{}' >> event.json
python-lambda-local -t 15 -f lambda_handler lambda_function.py event.json
```

Answer (score 1):

As 1.4 is not yet released...

Last week i needed exactly the same thing. Therefore i created a small mock server that can be run locally:
https://github.com/martinlindenberg/JawsLocalServer

- All headers and parameters were copied to the event-object that is passed to the handler.
- The context object is a simple object that forwards the data to the response object

Answer (score 0):

As of the date of this post, you can run functions locally by doing `sls function run [name-of-function]`. Any json used in your function's `event.json` will be passed into your function.

For testing your endpoints, you can also use [Serverless Offline](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline) which is a fork of the `serverless-serve` project.