# How to execute AWS lambda function from my local system

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have AWS Lambda Function(index.js) written in Node.js which has external dependency on other npm packages, when i try test the lambda function i have to zip the file and the node modules which is time consuming. 
Please help in finding a way to execute the function locally.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I can see the advantages of local testing. Take a look at these open source projects:

1. [lambda-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local): test Lambda functions on
   your local machine with sample event data
2. [emulambda](https://github.com/fugue/emulambda): a Python wrapper that emulates the
   AWS Lambda API locally

Also see this Stack Overflow post: [How to test aws lambda functions locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884968/how-to-test-aws-lambda-functions-locally?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Our command-line tool, bst proxy, does exactly what you are looking for:
https://bespoken.tools/blog/2016/08/24/introducing-bst-proxy-for-alexa-skill-development

It will make your lambda code accessible via URL, which you can then test with yourself or use with a real Alexa device. To use it, you install bst with npm:

```
sh
npm install bespoken-tools -g
```

And then run it:

```
bst proxy lambda index.js
```

You can then use the URL that is printed out to test away.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test more complex AWS lambda functions where development time and local infrastructure is the key. Is usage of their official [AWS Lambda docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs).

Simple Dockerfile example from documentation:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:12

# Copy function code
COPY app.js ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```