# I have downloaded a lambda function from my aws account(deployment package and SAM file) , how do I run this function locally on Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, aws-lambda

The lambda function is not functioning as expected and I would like to debug it on IDE , Intellij IDEA . I have the source code , libraries ( as a part of the downloaded deployment package) and template.yaml (SAM file).
I tried to do some research on how to run this function locally , in vain. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test aws lambda functions locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884968/how-to-test-aws-lambda-functions-locally)

Comment: Just for your information, there is this web-based IDE SLAppForge Sigma which streamlines the development, testing and deployment of serverless applications
https://sigma.slappforge.com/

Comment: You can also debug using cloudwatch logs.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can test your AWS Lambda code locally, 
is by using the [ServerlessFramework](https://serverless.com/) and the [Serverless-Offline](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline) plugin

Using Serverless Framework will also help you for creating the Infra you may require for deploying the functions to any of the major Cloud vendors including AWS.

You will need to maintain a serverless.yaml file which gets created for you when you create a serverless framework template.

**You can follow these reference links -**
 1. https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/
 2. https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/